# Rails 3 - PaperClip for Images with Versioning - Possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm hoping to hear your recommendations on using paperclip for images with versioning.

Anyone know of any elegant paper_clip image, versioning implementation solutions?

Use Case, User Uploads an image. User then uploads an image to replace the previous update. The user can see a trail of images.

Thank you

Comment: Curious on this one too.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :current_attachment, class_name: 'Attachment'
  has_many :attachments, order: 'attachments.created_at ASC'
end
```

and in the controller that is handling the image upload after you successfully create the new Attachment record, replace the existing User#current_attachment with the newly created one.

If you want a version number you could add a counter_cache for the attachments that a user has and use it's value on a before_create callback on Attachment.